# Groovy - Combining a list of Maps into a single Map

Tags: dictionary, groovy

I have a list of maps which I am trying to combine into a single map. I've tried using `map.collectEntries()` to do so, but the map that was created contained only the last map from the list. My input list is following:

```
def people = [[name:'John', age:35], [name:'Jim', age:54]]
```

I expect to calculate a map like:

```
def people = ['John':35, 'Jim':54]
```

Comment: What should the resulting map look like?

Comment: I have updated my question to show what the resulting map should look like.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Groovy, but in Java you could do something like `people.stream().collect(toMap(m -> m.get("name"), m -> m.get("age")))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to collect entries from the map with a closure that access name and age

```
def people = [[name:'John', age:35], [name:'Jim', age:54], [name:'Smith', age:'53']]

def nameAgeMap=people.collectEntries() {
    [it.name, it.age]
}

println(nameAgeMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

**For simplicity:**

```
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (Map<String, String> singleMap : people) {
  result.putAll(singleMap);
}
```

**Stream API:**

You can do the same using the stream API, which might look for many developers overcomplicated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tested using the Groovy Console and the resulting map only contains a map containing a single key/value pair - [name:'Jim', age:54]

Comment: Compared to `collectEntries` this also looks overcomplicated to a Groovy developer ;P

Comment: @cfrick: Have you seen the original question? It has changed a lot since the time of my answer. The original question was not in a Groovy style, but 90% plain Java style. There was List<Map<String, String>>, numbers were represented by strings, etc. The expectation is now different, too.